# Convert from RPM to per second

Tags: unit

Is this correct please for my conversion from RPM to per second? I've included my working below:

(500 / 60) * 2 * π = 500 rpm to just s<sup>-1</sup>.

Comment: I assume you're a younger poster, but you can easily find this by just Googling instead of needing to specifically ask. But no, it is not correct. You asked for rotations per second, not radians per second.

Comment: Sorry I don’t mean rotations per second, but just per second

Comment: You can't say "just per second". You must say what kind of event or phenomenon you are counting per second, along with appropriate units.

Comment: "*Just per second*" is meaningless. Even Hz is technically cycles per second. In this case one rotation would be one cycle.

Comment: @DKNguyen, $s^{-1}$ is common in Germany. I've seen it on many machine displays to indicate rotary speed or cycles per second. Usually the label prefixing the numerical display would make it clear what is being counted per second.

Comment: @Transistor That's just Hz which is cycles per second, since cycles is often omitted because...reasons(?), but doesn't change the fact OP does not really understand what it is they are reading or asking for.

Comment: @Herbert `per second` means `how many every second` ... it does not specify `how many of what?`

Answer (score 1):

60 RPM = 1 s<sup>-1</sup>.

To convert RPM to s<sup>-1</sup> you divide by 60. You only need π if you are dealing in radians.

Comment: Hi, sorry im confused, is this still correct even if I want to get rid of the revolutions and just make it per second please?

Comment: Think! If something rotates once per second how many times will it rotate in a minute? In two minutes? In ten minutes? (RPM = *revolutions* per minute, not *radians* per minute.)

Comment: @Herbert That's impossible. Your problem is the understanding of units, not any conversion calculation.

Comment: The $s^{-1}$ is the same as $/s$ and implies revolutions / second.

Answer (score 0):

So for 1020rpm

1020/60 revs per second ie 17 revs per second